# Editing several textviews at once as a group

Tags: android, textview

My app is table-styled (with a TableLayout and multiple textviews). I wonder if there is a way to form some sort of group of textviews which will then be manipulated as a single object.

For example, a group of all textviews in the right column. If I want to assign the same value to all of them, i just assign that value to the group. Or change their style at once.

It would be easier to maintain when I add new rows, I won't have to edit everything manually, just add new textviews to required groups.

Answer (score 1):

As for editing the text all at once, there is no way to do that. However, if you want to group them, you can use a LinearLayout. The list of functions you can perform while your TextViews are in the LinearLayout are listed here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

You can group the TextViews using a LinearLayout with vertical orientation instead TableLayout, and then make a method to set the values of all the childs:

```
LinearLayout lnlContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnlContainer);
for(int i = 0; i < lnlContainer.getChildCount(); i++){
    View child = lnlContainer.getChildAt(i);
    //Check if its a TextView
    if(child instanceof TextView){
        ((TextView)child).setText(getString(R.string.group_text));
        //Or something would like to make of all the TextViews like change the font
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does not quite suit me since groups may include different textviews, not necessarily the ones going one by one. Right-side textviews were just an example.

Comment: Other way its holding the references in a collection like a list/map per group, and then perform a linear round of the elements and perform the set of the text or style.